# Custom function not returning a string value in php

Tags: php

I am trying to check file extension. For this I have created a function but it is not returning any value. I really can't figure out where I am wrong. Below is the code :

```
function checkType($name){
        $farray = explode('.',$name);
        $fname  = trim($farray[0]);
        $fext = trim($farray[1]);
        echo $fext;
        return $fext;
    }
```

Code from where I am calling this function is :

```
$filename = "IMG_3552.JPG";
echo $filename;
checkType($filename);
echo "File Extension is : ". $fext;
```

On running following is echoed:
IMG_3552.JPG

File Extension is :

Please help ??

Comment: your not storing the return value `$fext` in anything. if you want your last echo to work you need `$fext = checkType($filename);`. the `$fext` inside your function exists only in your function, no where else.

Comment: why not simply use `pathinfo( $name, PATHINO_EXTENSION )`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a variable that is within the scope of the function.

You are returning a value from the function not the variable itself so the function is the value.

This is what you are supposed to be doing.

```
$filename = "IMG_3552.JPG";
echo $filename;
$fext = checkType($filename);
echo "File Extension is : ". $fext;
```

Also you can retrieve the extensiton of a file using `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` like this...

```
function checkType($name){
        $fext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        return $fext;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns a value.

You have to capture that returned value to an variable before using it. Since `$fext` is only available inside your function.

If you do,

```
$fext = checkType($filename);
echo "File Extension is : ". $fext;
```

It should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and also for explaining the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `function` that calculates the extension, but your `$fext` variable within the `function` is local, therefore it does not exist outside the `function` where you try to use it. To be able to use it, return the value and initialise it, like this:

```
function checktype( $name ){
    return pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
}

$name='IMG_3552.JPG';
$fext=checktype( $name );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
function checkType($name){
        $farray = explode('.',$name);
        $fname  = trim($farray[0]);
        $fext = trim($farray[1]);
        echo $fext;
        return $fext;
}
$filename = "IMG_3552.JPG";
echo $filename;
$fext = checkType($filename);
echo "File Extension is : ". $fext; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable $fext is a scope variable which is not usable outside your function. Try to get the return value of function in any other variable and write down it.

```
$filename = "IMG_3552.JPG";
$result = checkType($filename);
echo "Result: " . $result;
```

1 more thing i want to clear, why can't you use pathinfo to get the file extension? as you done the code, suppose you have such a file which have named with dot(.) then your logic will not work.
e.g. Suppose you have a file named: 'IMG.3552.jpg' than your code is not working as you use explode and use 1'st key of the result. so it will gives u 3552 instead of jpg.

I prefer to use

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```